# Redirect 404 error automatically to home in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, http-status-code-404

How can I redirect 404 errors using Symfony2 to another route, for example to my home.

I want if an user try to enter in /badspelling.php doesn't show 404 error page, instead of this I need to redirect to my /home.php

Is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to redirect all 404 errors to common route?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24771816/how-to-redirect-all-404-errors-to-common-route)

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is identical to this: [Show a specific route instead of error page (404)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15983082/show-a-specific-route-instead-of-error-page-404-symfony2)
(change only the page to which redirect)